# Silverlight ToolTipService

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I am setting the toolTip to button dynamically using  :

```
ToolTipService.SetToolTip(btnhello, "Hello World !");
```

I need to add additional some data dynamically in this tooltip with xaml control.

Any ideas on how to resolve the issue?

Comment: Your question doesn't really have enough information to go on to answer more completely.

Comment: What data control are you using? DataGrid?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use data binding.